# Lock balloon in mapview?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-mapview

I have problem about google map.

When I touch the screen I am adding pin in google map and When I touch the pin balloon is opening.  Everything is ok from now.

My question is when I click the balloon adding pin also.

I don't want to do it.

How can I lock this situation?

This is screenshot:

[image]

My code:` public void AddPoint(Drawable drawable, MapView mapView, MotionEvent event) {

```
    p = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels((int)event.getX(),(int)event.getY());
    final MapController mc = mapView.getController();
    mc.setZoom(16);
    CustomItemizedOverlay<CustomOverlayItem> itemizedOverlay = new CustomItemizedOverlay<CustomOverlayItem>(drawable, mapView);

    itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(new CustomOverlayItem(p,"","",""));
    mapView.getOverlays().add(itemizedOverlay);
    mc.animateTo(p);
    mapView.postInvalidate();

}`
```

onTap method:`

```
package com.example;



import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import com.google.android.maps.*;

import java.util.List;


public abstract class BalloonItemizedOverlay<Item extends OverlayItem> extends ItemizedOverlay<Item> {

    private MapView mapView;
    private BalloonOverlayView<Item> balloonView;
    private View clickRegion;
    private int viewOffset;
    final MapController mc;
    private Item currentFocussedItem;
    private int currentFocussedIndex;

    /**
     * Create a new BalloonItemizedOverlay
     * 
     * @param defaultMarker - A bounded Drawable to be drawn on the map for each item in the overlay.
     * @param mapView - The view upon which the overlay items are to be drawn.
     */
    public BalloonItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, MapView mapView) {
        super(defaultMarker);
        this.mapView = mapView;
        viewOffset = 0;
        mc = mapView.getController();
    }

    /**
     * Set the horizontal distance between the marker and the bottom of the information
     * balloon. The default is 0 which works well for center bounded markers. If your
     * marker is center-bottom bounded, call this before adding overlay items to ensure
     * the balloon hovers exactly above the marker. 
     * 
     * @param pixels - The padding between the center point and the bottom of the
     * information balloon.
     */
    public void setBalloonBottomOffset(int pixels) {
        viewOffset = pixels;
    }
    public int getBalloonBottomOffset() {
        return viewOffset;
    }

    /**
     * Override this method to handle a "tap" on a balloon. By default, does nothing 
     * and returns false.
     * 
     * @param index - The index of the item whose balloon is tapped.
     * @param item - The item whose balloon is tapped.
     * @return true if you handled the tap, otherwise false.
     */
    protected boolean onBalloonTap(int index, Item item) {
        return false;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay#onTap(int)
     */
    @Override
    protected final boolean onTap(int index) {

        currentFocussedIndex = index;
        currentFocussedItem = createItem(index);

        createAndDisplayBalloonOverlay();

        mc.animateTo(currentFocussedItem.getPoint());

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Creates the balloon view. Override to create a sub-classed view that
     * can populate additional sub-views.
     */
    protected BalloonOverlayView<Item> createBalloonOverlayView() {
        return new BalloonOverlayView<Item>(getMapView().getContext(), getBalloonBottomOffset());
    }

    /**
     * Expose map view to subclasses.
     * Helps with creation of balloon views. 
     */
    protected MapView getMapView() {
        return mapView;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the visibility of this overlay's balloon view to GONE. 
     */
    protected void hideBalloon() {
        if (balloonView != null) {
            balloonView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Hides the balloon view for any other BalloonItemizedOverlay instances
     * that might be present on the MapView.
     * 
     * @param overlays - list of overlays (including this) on the MapView.
     */
    private void hideOtherBalloons(List<Overlay> overlays) {

        for (Overlay overlay : overlays) {
            if (overlay instanceof BalloonItemizedOverlay<?> && overlay != this) {
                ((BalloonItemizedOverlay<?>) overlay).hideBalloon();
            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * Sets the onTouchListener for the balloon being displayed, calling the
     * overridden {@link #onBalloonTap} method.
     */
    private OnTouchListener createBalloonTouchListener() {
        return new OnTouchListener() {

            float startX;
            float startY;

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                View l =  ((View) v.getParent()).findViewById(R.id.balloon_main_layout);
                Drawable d = l.getBackground();

                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    int[] states = {android.R.attr.state_pressed};
                    if (d.setState(states)) {
                        d.invalidateSelf();
                    }
                    startX = event.getX();
                    startY = event.getY();
                    return true;
                } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    int newStates[] = {};
                    if (d.setState(newStates)) {
                        d.invalidateSelf();
                    }
                    if (Math.abs(startX - event.getX()) < 40 &&
                            Math.abs(startY - event.getY()) < 40 ) {
                        // call overridden method
                        onBalloonTap(currentFocussedIndex, currentFocussedItem);
                    }
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }

            }
        };
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay#getFocus()
     */
    @Override
    public Item getFocus() {
        return currentFocussedItem;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay#setFocus(Item)
     */
    @Override
    public void setFocus(Item item) {
        currentFocussedItem = item;

        if (currentFocussedItem == null){
            hideBalloon();
        }
        else{
            createAndDisplayBalloonOverlay();
        }   
    }


    private boolean createAndDisplayBalloonOverlay(){
        boolean isRecycled;
        if (balloonView == null) {
            balloonView = createBalloonOverlayView();
            clickRegion = (View) balloonView.findViewById(R.id.balloon_inner_layout);
            clickRegion.setOnTouchListener(createBalloonTouchListener());
            isRecycled = false;
        } else {
            isRecycled = true;
        }

        balloonView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
        if (mapOverlays.size() > 1) {
            hideOtherBalloons(mapOverlays);
        }

        if (currentFocussedItem != null)
            balloonView.setData(currentFocussedItem);

        GeoPoint point = currentFocussedItem.getPoint();
        MapView.LayoutParams params = new MapView.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, point,
                MapView.LayoutParams.BOTTOM_CENTER);
        params.mode = MapView.LayoutParams.MODE_MAP;

        balloonView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        if (isRecycled) {
            balloonView.setLayoutParams(params);
        } else {
            mapView.addView(balloonView, params);
        }

        return isRecycled;
    }

}
`
```

Answer (score 0):

For adding pin, i think you used overlay and you are hanling onDraw() and onTap() method of Overlay class. you are doing both pinning and opening baloon in onTap() method. So for pinning handle onTap(). and for opening baloon handle click event on pin.